# Hide virtual keyboard in windows 8 metro

Tags: windows-8

Now i am working on Windows 8 Metro application. For that i have a popup window with textbox and OK button. I need to hide Virtual Keyboard when "Enter" is clicked on Virtual keyboard. If i click "OK" button on popup keyboard hides automatically.

I got [this Link](http://nicoploner.blogspot.in/2012/08/windows-8-hide-virtual-keyboard.html) as good reference (using HiddenField). Is there any way to done this work without using "HiddenField". Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well finally found a solution for this issue.. I just change the focus from textbox to button in my popup.. below is the sample code..

```
public void FocusTextbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // set focus to textbox on popup open
        Textbox.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Programmatic);
    }

public void Textbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // conforming the "Enter" button click
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
            // change the focus to OK button
            this.OkButton.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Pointer);
        }
    }
```

Change the focus before closing the popup... it works great now..
And changing the focus to Label or Textblock is not hiding the Virtual keyboard...

Answer (score 0):

i was also looking for this , but i found [this approach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2012/07/09/tips-and-tricks-for-c-metro-developers-handling-the-virtual-keyboard.aspx) first

Comment: thanks for your response @Aviatrix.. i got one simple solution for this issue.. just check below answer...